RPC node can't find other nodes
The issue is that my RPC node can't find other nodes to download snapshot. I have tried commented out options in different combinations but nothing worked (log output is the same). In testnet the node also can't find any RPCs.
My node is behind NAT, so port forwarding is in place.
OS: Arch Linux.
Kernel version: 6.4.8-arch1-1.
Solana version: 1.18.15.
    #!/bin/zsh
    #RUST_LOG=solana=debug 
    exec solana-validator \
        --identity validator-keypair.json \
        --log - \
        --rpc-port 8799 \
        --entrypoint entrypoint.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
        #--vote-account vote-account-keypair.json \
        #--no-voting \
        #--rpc-bind-address 0.0.0.0 \
        #--expected-shred-version 50093 \
        #--dynamic-port-range 8000-8020 \
        #--limit-ledger-size \
        #--entrypoint entrypoint2.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
        #--known-validator CvSb7wdQAFpHuSpTYTJnX5SYH4hCfQ9VuGnqrKaKwycB \
        #--known-validator 6D2jqw9hyVCpppZexquxa74Fn33rJzzBx38T58VucHx9 \
        #--known-validator 26pV97Ce83ZQ6Kz9XT4td8tdoUFPTng8Fb8gPyc53dJx \
        #--known-validator he1iusunGwqrNtafDtLdhsUQDFvo13z9sUa36PauBtk \
        #--known-validator FKsC411dik9ktS6xPADxs4Fk2SCENvAiuccQHLAPndvk \
        #--full-rpc-api \
        #--only-known-rpc \
        #--private-rpc \
        #--entrypoint entrypoint3.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
        #--entrypoint entrypoint4.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
        #--entrypoint entrypoint5.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
        #--entrypoint mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
        #--no-incremental-snapshots \

Here are log excerpts:


Suggestions in the error message did't help.

Did you find the solution? I also don't find any RPC nodes for this shred version.

Not yet, it’s on pause.
